# What is the simplest way to track duration of usage of chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, browser-extension, event-tracking

I want to trigger an event only if the app have been used for at least n hours after installation .

I am aware of using google analytics or some other external services like plausible.
I don't want to over-complicate to that extent. How do I do that locally without any external services.

The idea I have is to use tracking variable and store the variable in `chrome.storage`
I am hoping more standard well known approaches are there to refine my idea.

Comment: It all depends on how you define "used"

Comment: @ThomasMueller `used` obviously doesn't mean installed but never triggered. Let say `used` mean total time of any code in content-script.js being executed. I wanted to add up both `content-script.js` and `background.js` time but for sake of simplicity lets start with only `content-script.js`

Comment: @ThomasMueller The reason why you asked is probably you have a solution which needs only the time of installation . is that readily available ? I though I would get that in [ExtensionInfo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/management/ExtensionInfo) but couldn't find that either.

Comment: There's no specific API for extensions, so just use the standard web stuff for tracking usage.